# Rails - button_to and submit

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3.2.3 application I'm using Ajax and jQuery. There is a button on a page. By clicking this button it must be disables, a spinner must be appeared and an ajax request begins. It's working only if I don't disable the button. If I disable it then an ajax request is not run.

So what I need to do is to be able send an ajax request, show a spinner and disable a button at the same time.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
         $("#lnk_more").click(function() {
            //if I uncomment this then an ajax request won't be be sent
            // $("#lnk_more").attr('disabled','disabled'); 
            $("#spinner").show(); 
         });
    </script>

    <%= button_to "More", {:controller => 'home', :action => "test_method", :page=>@current_page }, {:remote => true,:id => 'lnk_more', :method => :get} %>

<%= image_tag('ajax-loader.gif',:style => 'display:none', :id => 'spinner') %>

#result html
<form action="/home/test_method?page=1" class="button_to" data-remote="true" method="get"><div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [button_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) documentation. In the last example you'll find an example with :disable_with parameter, which you can use it to disable the button after submit.